# Как обновить данные с помощью спред-оператора

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Пытаюсь с помощью конструкции

```
const handle = id => {
   setValue([...updated, { id: id, value: 0 }])
}
```

и использования спред-оператора добавить/обновить строку, но получаю дублирование строки, если значение `id` уже существует:

```
[
    0: {id: 1, value: 0}
    1: {id: 1, value: 0}
]
```

Прошу подсказать, как получить результат без дублирования, а также можно ли одновременно изменить значение `value` на противоположное так, чтобы получился такой результат:

```
[
    0: {id: 1, value: 1}
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно найти в массиве элемент с определенным `id` и изменить у него значение `value` с 0 на 1 (или с 1 на 0):

```
const handle = id => {
  setValue(prev =>
    prev.map(item =>
      item.id === id
        ? {
          ...item,
          value: 1 - value
        }
        : item
    )
  )
}
```